# Can I use ORMlite/SQLlite outside of a containing application

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite

I want to unit test a DatabaseService class I have created ( Modified a WishList application I found online )
        package com.test.db;

```
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.util.List;
    import android.content.Context;
    import com.test.model.WishList;

    public class WishListService
    {
        private static WishListService instance;

        public static void init(Context ctx)
        {
            if (null == instance)
            {
                instance = new WishListService(ctx);
            }
        }

        static public WishListService getInstance()
        {
            return instance;
        }

        private DatabaseHelper helper;

        private WishListService(Context ctx)
        {
            helper = DatabaseHelper.getInstance(ctx);
        }

        public List<WishList> getAllWishLists()
        {
            List<WishList> wishLists = null;
            try
            {
                wishLists = helper.getWishListDao().queryForAll();
            } catch (SQLException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return wishLists;
        }

        public void addWishList(WishList l)
        {
            try
            {
                helper.getWishListDao().create(l);
            } catch (SQLException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public WishList getWishListWithId(int wishListId)
        {
            WishList wishList = null;
            try
            {
                wishList = helper.getWishListDao().queryForId(wishListId);
            } catch (SQLException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return wishList;
        }

        public void deleteWishList(WishList wishList)
        {
            try
            {
                helper.getWishListDao().delete(wishList);
            } catch (SQLException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


        public void updateWishList(WishList wishList)
        {
            try
            {
                helper.getWishListDao().update(wishList);
            } catch (SQLException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
```

My question is is there any way to instantiate the DatabaseHelper without having to create a test activity and pass it in as the Context that DatabaseHelper requires?
Ideally I want to Unit test this class as a standard JUnit test ,  not an Android JUnit test

Comment: **Assuming** your "DatabaseHelper" is a subclass of `SQLiteOpenHelper` you can pass it a _mock context_, e.g. `android.test.mock.MockContext` and implement the `openOrCreateDatabase` & `getDatabasePath` methods of the mock by calling `SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(..)` & returning the result.

Comment: Do I still need to run within an Emulator or physical device?  Ideally I don't want to have any dependency on an android device.

Comment: `SQLiteDatabase` has a lot of native functions, so you'd still be running on an emulator.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is a good idea.  [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) has non-Android JDBC package that you could use to drive Sqlite directly via JDBC.  However if the goal is to test your Android database classes, you will be running a lot of non-android code which would, in my view, invalidate the tests.  I'm considered mocking out all of the Android classes but it starts to become a maze of twisting passages before long.

I think your best way to proceed would be to put up with the Android junit tests.  Take a look at the [ORMLite Android test package files](http://ormlite.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/ormlite/ormliteAndroidTest/src/com/j256/ormlite/android/) for examples.  The [BaseDaoTest file] has all of the setup/shutdown methods that you can customize for your own tests.